# What files does setlocale() use?

Tags: c, linux

Compiling on the shared CentOS server is not allowed. Therefore, I compile my program in my Debian computer, linking it with Debian's system libraries such as libc, etc. Then I upload my program and the Debian system libraries and my program works. The only problem is that setlocale() does not work at CentOS. CentOS has "en_US.utf8" installed and works on all programs except mine. I suspect that I have to also upload Debian's locale files ? How could I link my program to the Debian locale files ? I tried to use LOCPATH but I am unsure of how it works exactly. Which files do I have to link to and how ?

C program:

```
setenv("LOCPATH", "/", 1);

if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8") == NULL) {
    puts("not set");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "locale files"? Translated messages for `gettext`?

Comment: @larsmans `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` and maybe others ?

Comment: Use `strace your_program` to find out what setlocale() actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a hex editor to modify the path to `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` which apparently is the only file that `setlocale()` uses according to `strace`. This method is dirty but it worked.

According to [man LOCPATH](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Tru64/man5/LOCPATH.5.html), this environment variable is non-standard, so its use is not recommended. No examples are given anywhere of how to use it nor what is meant exactly by a path to "locale's object files".

I guess the only real way of modifying the path is a glibc modification and recompilation.

Answer (score -1):

Quote: `LOCPATH is an environment variable that tells the setlocale() function the name of the directory from which to load locale object files. If LOCPATH is not defined, the default directory /usr/lib/nls/locale is searched. LOCPATH is similar to the PATH environment variable; it contains a list of z/OS UNIX directories separated by colons.`

So just specifying `/` and hoping that it does a recursive search will not work.

You could also produce a static binary and upload that to the host.

Comment: Debian does not use `/usr/lib/nls/locale`. It may be that that path is only valid in IBM, since I think you have quoted them ?

Comment: This answer is IBM specific, has nothing to do with either CentOS or Debian